# Goldfarb Idnani quadratic solver

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization

I am implementing the Support Vector Regression (SVR) algorithm by means of quadratic programming. In order to do that, I am using an optimization library that contains a quadratic solver based on the Goldfarb Idnani active set quadratic optimization method.

However, the library seems not to be working the way I was expecting. Once the optimization process is finished, not all the constraints are active, so there are some variables for which the value is out of the valid range of values in an SVR problem.

I implemented SVR in the past in Matlab by means of the quadprog method, and I did not have such issues. Of course, I reviewed and debugged my own code.

My question is: is it normal that, after finishing the Goldfarb Idnani algorithm, some of the constraints are not active? Or should I assume that the library is not working properly?

PS: I have read the original paper<sup>[[1](http://www.javaquant.net/papers/goldfarbidnani.pdf)]</sup>, and from it I guess that all constraints should be active at the end of the process.

<sup>[1]</sup> "A numerically stable dual method for solving strictly convex quadratic programs", D. Goldfarb, A. Idnani, Mathematical Programming 27, pp. 1–33, 1983. Available at http://www.javaquant.net/papers/goldfarbidnani.pdf.

Comment: "by means of quadratic programming." *Why?* --most libraries use some variants of SMO.

Comment: Compared to my Matlab quadprog implementation, the Matlab SMO one was extremely slow.

Comment: "and from it I guess that all constraints should be active at the end of the process." I think not. Only the constraint corresponding to the support vectors should be...but I could be wrong I haven't programmed that sort of thing for years now.

Comment: @siew To get a proper comparison of solver performance, compare your `quadprog` implementation with libraries like LIBSVM or SVM$^{light}$.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: is my comment above yours correct? --else I delete it b/c it could be misleading.

Comment: @user603 it seems OK to me. Note that all primal-dual related constraints must hold for all training instances, regardless of whether they become support vectors. This is a direct result of the problem formulation though so I guess that's a minor detail.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try SMO out. However, I am still curious about that library's odd behavior.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: yes, I understand. I read the OP's use of the word 'active' in the sense of 'binding'. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PabloSuau, I met similar problem. How is this going finally? Is the library wrong? (I used the implementation in R package quadprog)

Comment: Hi. I ended up using libsvm...

Comment: I would suggest check the paper, Walking an extra mile never done a harm i guess, It says the problem should be "Strictly" convex for Goldfarb Idnani algorithm . If the problem is not convex god knows what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

If hard constraints of the optimization problem are violated in the solution there is most definitely a problem in your implementation. A solution is required to adhere to all constraints. Note that this does *not* mean the solution must be somewhere on the boundary of the feasible region (in contrast to linear programming).

Comment: Thank you Marc. Since the results of my code prior to the quadprog bit are the same than those of my previous matlab implementation, is it feasible to think that the library is not well implemented?

Comment: Either that or you are somehow calling it wrong. I am usually hesitant to assume libraries are in error, especially if they are very popular, though it certainly does happen. In case of a bug you get the opportunity to help improve the library, which is nice.

Comment: another possibility is that you have *many* support vectors: I can see how if the number of support vectors is close to the number of data points, then SMO would lose it's edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the code correctly, all your constraints should be satisfied in the end.

I noticed one problem in that repo, go to line 13 of QuadProg++.hh

```
CI^T x + ci0 >= 0
```

in code it should be CI^T x - ci0 >= 0, as shown in compute_mult_minus_vector(). Maybe you're misguided by this comment ?